# Cairo: cairo_text_extents returning incorrect size

Tags: c++, cairo, freetype2

When using cairo_text_extents with font hint style set to CAIRO_HINT_STYLE_SLIGHT the bounding box returned is incorrect for some fonts. For Verdana it works correctly, however using Vera, the bounding box is smaller than the string size.

Using the default hint style on both fonts works correctly.

Am I missing something else that I should be setting/doing to make cairo_text_extents play nicely with font hints?

Comment: For my implementation, the `x_advance` part of `cairo_text_extents_t` worked better than using `width`.

Comment: Using x_advance works better for me too, thanks!

Comment: And remember font height is in point, extents->height is in pixel, `0.75 pt = 1 px`